Robocorp java.select_window_by_title throws 'Invalid window handle.'
I’m building a Java robot on Windows 10 64-bit, 64 bit Java, latest JRE (v1.8.0_411). Fresh install of Robocorp VSCode plugins (Robocorp Code v1.22.3, Robot Framework Language Server v1.12.0).
My code is based on the official docs: https://robocorp.com/docs/libraries/rpa-framework/rpa-javaaccessbridge/keywords#list-java-windows
Code tasks.py:
from robocorp.tasks import task
from RPA.JavaAccessBridge import JavaAccessBridge, ContextTree
import subprocess

# initialize the Java Access Bridge
java = JavaAccessBridge()

@task
def minimal_task():
    subprocess.Popen(
        ["C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre\\bin\\java.exe", "-jar", "BasicSwing.jar", "test"],
        shell=True,
        cwd="C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\",
        close_fds=True
    )
    java.select_window_by_title('test')

Code conda.yaml:
channels:
  - conda-forge

dependencies:
  - python=3.10.12                # https://pyreadiness.org/3.10
  - pip=23.2.1                    # https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news
  - robocorp-truststore=0.8.0     # https://pypi.org/project/robocorp-truststore/
  - pip:
    - rpaframework==28.4.0        # https://rpaframework.org/releasenotes.html
    - robocorp==1.6.2             # https://pypi.org/project/robocorp
    - robocorp-browser==2.2.1     # https://pypi.org/project/robocorp-browser
    - java-access-bridge-wrapper==1.2.0 # https://pypi.org/project/java-access-bridge-wrapper/

I receive following error when calling java.select_window_by_title(“test”)

============================ Running: minimal_task ============================= 2024-06-02 09:39:42,017 [INFO] {JavaAccessBridge.py:502} Java Access Bridge Wrapper initialized
2024-06-02 09:39:42,056 [INFO] {jab_wrapper.py:654} Found Java window
text=test pid=5264 hwnd=197616 vmID=c_long(197574) context=<JavaObject
object at 0x0000023239726D40>
2024-06-02 09:39:42,059 [INFO] {JavaAccessBridge.py:1068}
VMversion=1.8.0_411; BridgeJavaClassVersion=1.8.0_411;
BridgeJavaDLLVersion=1.8.0_411; BridgeWinDLLVersion=1.8.0_411
minimal_task status: FAIL
(1400, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'Invalid window handle.')
==================== Full Traceback (running minimal_task) ===================== Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\ProgramData\robocorp\ht\9cf649c_b1f3c24_09529949\lib\site-packages\robocorp\tasks_commands.py",
line 440, in run
result = task.run(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\robocorp\ht\9cf649c_b1f3c24_09529949\lib\site-packages\robocorp\tasks_task.py",
line 89, in run
return self.method(*args, **kwargs)   File "\mac\Home\Documents\Coding\codifly\robotframework-example\tasks.py",
line 16, in minimal_task
java.select_window_by_title('test')   File "C:\ProgramData\robocorp\ht\9cf649c_b1f3c24_09529949\lib\site-packages\RPA\JavaAccessBridge.py",
line 1204, in select_window_by_title
self._select_window(   File "C:\ProgramData\robocorp\ht\9cf649c_b1f3c24_09529949\lib\site-packages\RPA\JavaAccessBridge.py",
line 1271, in _select_window
self._bring_window_to_foreground()   File "C:\ProgramData\robocorp\ht\9cf649c_b1f3c24_09529949\lib\site-packages\RPA\JavaAccessBridge.py",
line 1284, in _bring_window_to_foreground
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle) pywintypes.error: (1400, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'Invalid window handle.')

What is causing the issue? Thanks for helping!
